# How to have variant type with more than one passable string in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, types, android-jetpack-compose

How to have variant type with more than one passable string in Jetpack Compose. If variant is passed from outside it should change the Text color based on the condition.
Shows an error if i have two values in variant type - `Expecting a top level declaration`.

```
@Composable
fun Label(
    label: String,
    variant: String = "dark" | "light"

) {
        Text(
            text = label,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
//if color = "dark" is passed from outside should change color.
            color = if (variant === "dark") Color.Black else Color.Yellow,
        )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only 2 values: `dark|light` you can use a `Boolean` instead of a `String`.

Something like:

```
@Composable
fun Label(
    label: String,
    variantLight : Boolean =true

) {
    Text(
        text = label,
        fontSize = 24.sp,
        color = if (variantLight) Color.Yellow else Color.Black
    )
}
```

And then use it with:

```
var variantLight by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Label(
    label = "Hello World",
    variantLight = variantLight
)
```

If you have more values you can use an enum class:

```
enum class VariantLabel {
    Light,
    Dark
}

@Composable
fun Label(
    label: String,
    variant: VariantLabel = VariantLabel.Light

) {
    Text(
        text = label,
        fontSize = 24.sp,
        color = if (variant == VariantLabel.Dark) Color.Black else Color.Yellow,
    )
}
```

and then use it with:

```
var variantLabel by remember { mutableStateOf(VariantLabel.Light) }

Label(
    label = "Hello World",
    variant = variantLabel
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hoist your `variant` state somewhere that uses your `Label` composable, and have it `remember` something that the `Label` can use to update its `State` , in your case its `Color`.

Parent `Composable` that uses `Label`

```
 var variant by remember { mutableStateOf("dark") }

 Button(onClick = {
        variant = "light"
 }){
       //Button Label here
 }

 Label(
      label = "Hello World",
      variant = variant
 )
```

Your `Label`

```
@Composable
fun Label(
    label: String,
    variant: String
) {
    Text(
        text = label,
        fontSize = 24.sp,
        color = if (variant === "dark") Color.Black else Color.Yellow,
    ) 
}
```